# What is "Advanced Mode" in Views 3?

Tags: views

In [this article](http://www.zivtech.com/blog/views-quality-checklist) the first instruction is

> On every site, run `drush vd` to turn the Views settings to the advanced mode.

What does this mean? A Google search for "Views advanced mode" yields mostly just links back to this article. What is "advanced mode"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Advanced mode means

> Set the Views settings to more developer-oriented values.

You can check the definition of this in views module Drush folder views.drush.inc file.

```
  $items['views-dev'] = array(
    'callback' => 'views_development_settings',
    'drupal dependencies' => array('views'),
    'description' => 'Set the Views settings to more developer-oriented values.',
    'bootstrap' => DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUPAL_FULL,
    'aliases' => array('vd'),
  );
```

Once drush vd command is executed following variables are set.

```
  variable_set('views_ui_show_listing_filters', TRUE);
  variable_set('views_ui_show_master_display', TRUE);
  variable_set('views_ui_show_advanced_column', TRUE);
  variable_set('views_ui_always_live_preview', FALSE);
  variable_set('views_ui_always_live_preview_button', TRUE);
  variable_set('views_ui_show_preview_information', TRUE);
  variable_set('views_ui_show_sql_query', TRUE);
  variable_set('views_ui_show_performance_statistics', TRUE);
  variable_set('views_show_additional_queries', TRUE);
  variable_set('views_devel_output', TRUE);
  variable_set('views_devel_region', 'message');
  variable_set('views_ui_display_embed', TRUE);
  $message = dt("Setup the new views settings.");
  drush_log($message, 'success');
```

You can do it with out using drush command too by navigating to "admin/structure/views/settings"